# MSVC 2013 Bug? Retrieving last element from mapped container

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, msvc12

Say I have a `std::map<std::string, std::vector<T>` and I want to write some code

that will return to me the element at the back of the mapped vector, given some key.

So I first write some code that will return to me the element at the end of a collection (vector in this case):

```
// get element at back of given collection
template<typename Collection>
auto ReturnLastObject(const Collection& collection) -> decltype(collection.back())&
{
    return collection.back();
}
```

So far so good.

Next, I realize that my function to actually do the logic will need to return the same type as `ReturnLastObject` would, so I write some helper struct that will allow me to use type traits to pull off the return type of a function pointer (anticipating that function pointer will be to `ReturnLastObject<U>`):

```
template<typename T>
struct GetReturnType;

template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct GetReturnType<Ret(*)(Args...)>
{
    using type = Ret;
};
```

Still doing pretty good:

Finally, I write the main function to either return the last element, or throw an exception:

```
template<typename MapType>
auto GetLastAddedObject(const typename MapType::key_type& key, const MapType& mapCollection)
    -> typename GetReturnType<decltype(&ReturnLastObject<typename MapType::mapped_type>)>::type&
{
    auto& objects = mapCollection.at(key);
    if (!objects.empty())
    {
        return ReturnLastObject(objects);
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not retrieve last added item.");
    }
}
```

This appears to work fine in both [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f8a736004b8b606) and [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6127c444348abeb7).

However, when I try compiling using MSVC 2013 (Update 3),
I get the following compiler error:

> error C2893: Failed to specialize function template `GetReturnType<unknown-type>::type &detail::GetLastAddedObject(const MapType::key_type &,const MapType &)`
>
>          With the following template arguments:
>
>                   `MapType=std::map<std::string,std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>>>`

### Question

What I'm asking is if there is a workaround in MSVC 2013 that can accomplish the same thing, or if I just did something wrong?

---

#### Edit: MCVE

(can also be found by following the GCC and Clang links)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace detail{
// helper struct for peeling off return type of function pointer
template<typename T>
struct GetReturnType;

template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct GetReturnType<Ret(*)(Args...)>
{
    using type = Ret;
};

// get element at back of given collection
template<typename Collection>
auto ReturnLastObject(const Collection& collection) -> decltype(collection.back())&
{
    return collection.back();
}

// GetLastAddedObject assumes that MapType is essentially a key mapped to a collection
// and we want to access the collection specified by the key, and return the element at the back of it
template<typename MapType>
auto GetLastAddedObject(const typename MapType::key_type& key, const MapType& mapCollection)
    -> typename GetReturnType<decltype(&ReturnLastObject<typename MapType::mapped_type>)>::type&
{
    auto& objects = mapCollection.at(key);
    if (!objects.empty())
    {
        return ReturnLastObject(objects);
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not retrieve last added item.");
    }
}
} //end namespace detail


int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> myMap;
    myMap["StackOverflow"] = {42};
    
    //...
    std::string key = "StackOverflow";
    auto&& lastAddedObject = detail::GetLastAddedObject(key, myMap);
    std::cout << std::forward<decltype(lastAddedObject)>(lastAddedObject) << std::endl; // should print "42
}
```

Comment: `std::map` doesn't even have a `back` function. If you want to do that part generically, use iterators.

Comment: @chris read his code, `back` is being applied to a `vector`, not a `map`

Comment: There seem to be much simpler ways to do this, is this just a minimal example of a problem encountered doing something more complex?

Comment: @chris: As twentylemon said, the container is a `std::vector`

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm not sure how I missed that because it's mentioned more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you?

I don't have VS2013 to test it.

```
namespace detail {

    template<typename MapType>
    typename MapType::mapped_type::value_type GetLastAddedObject(const typename MapType::key_type key, const MapType& mapCollection)
    {
        auto& objects = mapCollection.at(key);
        if (!objects.empty())
        {
            return objects.back();
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Could not retrieve last added item.");
        }
    }

} //end namespace detail
```

Comment: Simpler *and* compiles with MSVC 2013. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your return type:

```
template<typename MapType>
auto GetLastAddedObject(const typename MapType::key_type& key,
                        const MapType& mapCollection)
-> decltype(ReturnLastObject(mapCollection.at(key)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however this still does not compile in MSVC 2013 for me

Comment: @Jarrod42. It must be the version I'm using (update 3).